# jQueryUI Tabs - Linking Two Sets of Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two different sets of jqueryui tabs. The first tab set of tabs works perfectly. Every time I need to load a tab, it is automatically put into the first set of tabs. Each set of tabs is sortable.

I would like to be able to drag a tab from one set of tabs to the other. The content and the tab should disappear from one set of tabs and appear in the other set of tags, essentially allowing there to be two sets of tabs displaying at the same time. I have not been able to implement this and was wondering how I should go about linking the two sets of tabs.

Thanks and let me know if I need to explain something better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any kind of plugin that does what you are trying to achieve. The best and closest you can find is http://pastehtml.com/view/1by9nfd.html or http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs

I am not sure why do you need to do that but if possible, try considering a different approach
or build the tab like feature using `DIV` and throw it inside the draggable container mix it with the samples given in the links and play with it.

I highly doubt that someone will be able to provide you the exact sample you are looking for.

Comment: essentially, I am working on an editor similar to Notepad++ or a multitude of different text editors where you can view editors side by side, as well as use tabs.